# Outline of a country as a polygon

Tags: geography

I'd like to obtain a country map of France, as polygon xy positions so I can adjust the borders.

Currently I'm using:

```
i= GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[None], Polygon[France (country)]}, GeoBackground -> None, GeoZoomLevel->1]
```

Which returns an image.

I then obtain a white on black outline of the country by:

```
e = EdgeDetect[i]
```

I get the coordinates of the outline by looking for white pixels:

```
p = PixelValuePositions[e, 1]
```

And then draw an outline around it:

```
ListCurvePlot[p]
```

This sort of works, but the results are choppy and ListCurvePlot seems to miss a lot of the borders. Furthermore, PixelValuePositions just returns a set of points which are ordered by how their XY positions on the image, not necessarily by which points are adjacent on the map. This would not be a problem for a straight horizontal border, but with vertical and irregular lines adjacent points end up being non-adjacent.

Comment: See `CountryData["France", "SchematicCoordinates"]`. p.s. `GeoGraphics` is not an image but a `GraphicsBox` at the end (with image as background).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "FullCoordinates" property of the entity:

```
Entity["Country","France"]["FullCoordinates"]//Short
```

> {{{-49.5791,69.2829},{-49.5787,69.2793},<<2808>>,{-49.5779,69.2817}},{<<1>>},{<<1>>},<<880>>,{<<1>>},{<<1>>},{<<1>>}}

This returns the x,y coordinates of France and all of its territories. If you just want the x,y coordinates of the mainland, then you can extract the lat-long coordinates from the polygon using:

```
latlong = Entity["Country", "France"]["Polygon"][[1, 1]];
```

Note that the above returns a list of polygons, so reverse needs to be applied at level 3:

```
Reverse[latlong, {3}] //Short
```

> {{{-1.78469,43.3495},{-1.78446,43.3498},<<2476>>,{-1.73746,43.3301}},{{<<17>>,<<11>>},<<147>>}}

You can also use CountryData as suggested by @Kuba.